# Angles and Parallel

Tags: geometry

[image]

a and e are both (...), both have arms to the right on n
 g and b are both (...), both have arms to the left on n

I'm not getting this, I am taught in another language so I do not know what it's called in English the part where (...) that's supposed to be called. But here are the questions.

1. How does g have a arm on the left when the picture shows obviously on the right?
2. What are these supposed to be called in the part (...) in English?
3. Aren't there multiple choices as in, B and F, H and D and so on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i can't uderstand what you mean by "g and b are both (...), both have arms to the left on n and so on."

Comment: Same angle or something like that (...) But I just don't know the English word for it.

Comment: congruent? use google translator

Comment: Well I did, didn't even translate. I think it is congruent.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

a & e are CORRESPONDING ANGLES
c & f are ALTERNATE INTERIOR ANGLES
a & h are ALTERNATE EXTERIOR ANGLES
c & e are CONSECUTIVE INTERIOR ANGLES

Comment: Then what are g,b,d ?

Comment: They are nothing actually, we are not used to compare three angles in parallel lines. I mean not g = b = d. But surely, b=g, they are alternate exterior angles.